# Extra right brace in yacc output

Tags: c, yacc, lex

My lex file has:

```
word [^{}"=,\t\n@\\ ]+

\{  {
    return(LBRACE);
}

\}  {
    return(RBRACE);
}

{word}  {
     yylval = yytext; printf("WORD=%s",yytext); return(WORD);
}
```

My yacc file has:

```
phrase: LBRACE WORD RBRACE  {printf("LBRACE %s RBRACE\n",$2);};
```

On inputting:

```
{FooBar}
```

I get:

```
WORD=FooBar
LBRACE FooBar} RBRACE
```

I'm unsure why I'm getting the extra right brace even though I'm printing only $2, which should ideal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
{word}  {
     yylval = yytext; printf("WORD=%s",yytext); return(WORD);
}
```

The value of yytext is only valid while you are handling this lexeme. Once you move to the next lexeme the content of the bufffer may be overwritten. Thus saving the yytext pointer is not going to do you any good. You need to copy the token out of the buffer.

```
{word}   {  yylval = (char*)calloc(yylen+1, sizeof(char));
            strncpy(yylval, yytext, yylen); // Remember you need to free this.
            return WORD;
         }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think you mean the global variable `yyleng`, right? Also, shouldn't the `strncpy` should be over `yyleng + 1` characters to get the terminating null? If `strndup` is used, it would add the terminating null on its own.

Comment: @crypto: Yes I mean the global yylen provided by lex. You don't need the strncpy to copy yylen +1 because I use calloc() which guarantees to null out the underlying memory returned. So it does not matter if the strncpy adds the extra '\0' or not as it will be '\0' anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It's up to you to store the value of `yytext` (via `yylval`) in the `WORD` production.  It's just a pointer into the working space of lex.  You're seeing the working space change after it parses `RBRACE`.  Imagine a yacc rule like `LBRACE WORD COMMA WORD LBRACE` and what would be going on there.

If you don't want to have a separate production I think you can do `LBRACE WORD { code to strdup yylval } RBRACE { ... }`

Comment: Why is there a difference in the value of `$2` & the passed `yylval` string?

Comment: `yylval` is not a "string" per se, it's a *pointer* which points into lex private data.  You own `yylval` but you don't own what it points to.  It is only valid for a given terminal symbol between the time that `yylex()` returns and you call into it again.  Try `yylval = strdup(yytext)` to see what I mean.

Comment: strdup is not safe. There is no gurantee that the lex buffer is '\0' terminated. You need to use yylen to extract the part of the buffer you need.